# iphone security : Does the app screenshot get saved in cache even if backgrounding is removed?

Tags: iphone

From what I have read , I understand that iOS takes a screenshot whenever the app goes into the background and stores it in the cache for transition purposes. My client has security issues, therefore I have removed backgrounding from my app to make sure that the screenshot is not taken.

Now, I have read in some places, that this is not enough, I also need to put some sort of "white screen" to cover up my content or make sure that all fields are set as empty in applicationWillTerminate. Is this required ? and if I have removed backgrounding where does the screenshot get stored on the file system ?

Regards,
Harikant Jammi

Comment: where did you read this?

Comment: http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/01/14/whats-in-your-ios-image-cache-backgrounding-snapshot/

Comment: the link you provided has all the answers...